# What causes the SMS system to stop working and throw DB errors?

Tags: civisms, scheduled-job

I'm getting an error message on scheduled SMS.

Finished execution of Send Scheduled SMS with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

I'm running 4.7.8 and I think it was stable in 4.7.6. My WP install is 4.5.3

Comment: Are you able to send an individual SMS without error? What service provider are you using for your SMS?

Comment: More details about the DB error should be available in your CiviCRM debug log ([instructions to locate](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles)). If you find the "DB Error" in that logfile and share the backtrace here, you'll be able to get a more informed answer. Make sure no sensitive data (eg SMS provider login) is included :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will get onto that. The provider is Clickatell and the system works when I send on test SMS.

Comment: Finally had a chance to get back to this one. End of financial year is a killer!

db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="

Comment: @Chris Burgess How do I load the entire backtrace here? It's a bit long. Thanks!

Comment: @PeteRoss I'd use https://gist.github.com or a "pastebin" site (Google for this, you'll find plenty of options).

Comment: I had the same problem on Drupal 7 running Civi 4.7.10. Thanks for fix Raj

Answer (score 3):

This error does show up in Civi 4.7.8 on Drupal 7.x.  @PeteRoss Thanks.  Haven't had chance to upgrade to 4.7.9 yet.

Had to send scheduled event SMS to members, so modified sql in if statement in CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php

525  if ($mailing->sms_provider_id) {
  ....
  ....
  546                         OR       contact_a.do_not_sms = 0 )
- 547                         $aclWhere}";
+ 547                         $aclWhere";
  548     }

The scheduled SMS job completed successfully after the modification.

Comment: Is there a JIRA ticket open for this over at issues.civicrm.org?

Comment: I created https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9002

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Civi on WordPress was throwing an extra } into the query from the file Mailingjob.php line 547. I hope this helps someone else and is there some way we can check if this affects others?