# Do mass SMS work in 4.7.11 using Clickatell?

Tags: 4.7, sms

I can send a single SMS in 4.7.11 using Clickatell.  But a mass SMS fails with the following message from the cron task 'finished execution of Send Scheduled SMS with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error'.  I have installed version 3.0 of the Clickatell extension from Veda Consulting. Anyone know if this extension is supported in 4.7? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like fix is not present in v4.7.11. But there is a ticket already - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19327. Might be available in v4.7.12.

Anyway seems like a minor patch to apply?

Comment: Thanks - see also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/what-causes-the-sms-system-to-stop-working-and-throw-db-errors

Comment: This is fixed in 4.7.12